# angularjs $boadcast and $on doesn´t work from angular.injector

Tags: angularjs, broadcast

I´m trying to call a function into a Controller when received a Push Notification, passing for a $broadcast / factory, but the broadcast doesn´t work when calling by the angular.injector, here a peace of my code:

push.js

```
window.onNotification = function(data) {
        angular.injector(['ng', 'myApp']).get("laFactory").PushReceived(data.additionalData); // --> work fine
    };
         window.push = PushNotification.init({
             "android": {
                 "senderID": "123456789",
                 "icon": "system",
                 "forceShow": true
             }
         });

         window.push.on('notification', window.onNotification);
```

laFactory.js

```
.factory('laFactory', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    var laFactory = {};

    laFactory.PushReceived = function(data) {           
       $rootScope.$broadcast('handleNotify', {}); // --> don´t work when called by angular.injector!!! why not?!
    };

    $rootScope.$broadcast('handleNotify', {}); // this work fine

    return laFactory;
}
```

myController.js

```
.controller('NotificacoesController', function($scope, $rootScope, laFactory) {
    var handler = $scope.$on('handleNotify', function () {
            alert('broadcast - on');
    });
```

}

Comment: may be you `laFactory.PushReceived` not getting called try to log into console inside `laFactory.PushReceived` to see if its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is best, but it works:

```
angular.element(document).injector().invoke(["laFactory", function(laF) {
  laF.PushReceived({});
}]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/uVHZKxUjRErbxt2dR3lw?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you are trying to get the service this way?

Pretty sure the syntax you're using is creating a new injector if you want to get the existing one then you would use something like:

`angular.element(document).injector()`

Even still I wonder why you wouldn't just inject the services normally.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector

---

Ah I see now you're trying to get this outside of angular context... the above snippet will work but think you're better off typically just wrapping the notification code in a service instead of trying to use angular stuff outside of angular bring the other stuff "into the fold"  or search for existing modules that do this work for you.